# How to deserialize a complex JSON

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am new in Jackson and I need to deserialize JSON looks like the following:

```
{
  "companies": [{
    "id": "some_id",
    "type": "sale",
    "name": "Company1",
    "attributes": {
      "countPeople": 300,
      "salary": 3000
    }
  }, 
  {
    "id": "new_id",
    "type": "IT",
    "name": "Company2",
    "attributes": {
      "countPeople": 100,
      "salary": 5000,
      "city": "New York",
      ...
    }
  }]
}
```

I want to deserialize it to the DTO's looks like the following:

```
public class Companies {
    @JsonProperty("companies")
    public List<Company> companiesList;
}

public class Company {
    public String id;
    public String type;
    public String name;
    public Attributes attributes;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public Company(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                   @JsonProperty("type") String type,
                   @JSonProperty("name") String name,
                   @JsonProperty("attributes") Attributes attributes
    ) {
        ...
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "IT", value = ItAttributes.class)
        ...
})
public abstract Attributes {
    public int countPeople;
    ...
}

public class ItAttributes extends Attributes {
   ...
}
```

and when I was trying to deserialize the JSON

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Companies comp = mapper.readValue(json, Companies.class);
    }
}
```

I was getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.example.dto.Attributes]: missing type id property 'type' (for POJO property 'attributes')
```

Obviously the `Jackson` doesn't see the `type` property, but I don't understand why.
 How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to use `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` in an abstract `Company` as follows:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "IT", value = ItCompany.class)
        ...
})
public abstract Company {
    public String id;
    public String type;
    public String name;
}
```

Then you would have the concrete `Company` implementations:

```java
public class ItCompany {
    public ItAttributes attributes;
}

// Other Company types
```

And your `Attributes` class would be as follows:

```java
public abstract Attributes {
    public int countPeople;
    ...
}

public class ItAttributes extends Attributes {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for me as well.

Comment: You are welcome ;)